# Ruby - undefined method error

Tags: ruby, class, module, mongoid

I am trying to better structure my code. I have a module:

```
module Outlet

  class Base
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :method, type:String, presence:true
  end

  class Event < Base
  end

  class Action < Base
  end

end
```

and another module with a very similar structure to Outlet. So i extended it:

```
module Outlet::CustomURL

  class Event < Outlet::Event
    field :url,     type:String, presence:true
  end

end
```

In the end, I want to do something like this: `Outlet::CustomURL::Event.new(...)`

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `field' for Outlet::CustomURL::Event:Class
```

Comment: Ran this example without any problem, mongoid 2.2.4, ruby 1.9.3-p0. What versions do you have?